# MySQL 5.7 - Error sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql

After Updating to MySQL 5.7.11 we are getting a number of errors related to the sql_mode including only_full_group_by.

Research shows we can turn this off but it would probably be better to know how to achieve the intended goal with properly structured SQL statements.

**Error:**

> #1140 - In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'tblslideshow.slideImage'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

**Query:**

```
SELECT
   tblslideshow.slideImage,
   COUNT(tblslideshow.slideID) AS countVal
FROM
  tblslideshow
WHERE
  tblslideshow.parentID = 3424
```

The goal is to return a list of values but also a Count for all returned records.
What's the best way to achieve this goal without having to change the MySQL my.ini ? And why is it a Group By error is we're not even grouping? Or is Grouping part of the proper solution?

**Expected Result should be:**

```
slideImage        |      countVal

Image1.jpg        |      3

Image2.jpg        |      3 

Image3.jpg        |      3
```

Edit: Since we are using PHP and MySQLi it may be wiser to exclude the Count() and just use "mysqli_num_rows"

Comment: Using an aggregate function (`COUNT` here) *is* aggregation. Without `GROUP BY` this results in one row. MySQL complains about not knowing which `slideImage` to show in that one row.

Comment: You are missing a `GROUP BY`.  All of your non-aggregated columns must be in GROUP BY.

Comment: You are entirely correct. It was a crap query and the slideImage was not used elsewhere upon review of the rest of the pages code. The count() could have stood alone without the slideImage column. @D-Shih did produce a working query for the stated goal. And we are not ready for MySQL 8.0.11 yet.

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use *Aggregate function*, you need to add non-aggregate columns on  `Group by` clause.

```
SELECT
   tblslideshow.slideImage,
   COUNT(tblslideshow.slideID) AS countVal
FROM
  tblslideshow
WHERE
  tblslideshow.parentID = 3424
Group by tblslideshow.slideImage
```

**EDIT**

You can try to use subquery on `select`

```
SELECT t.slideImage,
(
    SELECT
       COUNT(tblslideshow.slideID) AS countVal
    FROM
      tblslideshow
    WHERE
      tblslideshow.parentID = 3424
) countVal
FROM tblslideshow t
WHERE t.parentID = 3424
```

Comment: Unfortunately that creates a countVal for each record as 1, rather than the goal of a total count of all records returned from the query.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Example provided. countVal should be the Count() or Sum of all records retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `COUNT OVER`, available as of MySQL 8.0:

```
SELECT
   tblslideshow.slideImage,
   COUNT(*) OVER () AS countVal
FROM
  tblslideshow
WHERE
  tblslideshow.parentID = 3424;
```

This keeps the single rows and adds the aggregate value to them.